# Need to create a REST-ful web service using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need a tutorial or a book which allows me to create a restful web service. I was trying to follow [this tutorial](http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/), but restify is not installing properly. After research I found DTrace is for Linux version and not supported for Windows OS.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Im sorry i think icldnt be able to explain my problem 
SIr my aim is to develop a restfull service in node.
thats all !!!
and i came accross the above link which is the tutorial for restfull webservice but im not able to install RESTIFY api on my windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have problems installing RESTIFY on windows due to dependencies, you can try with Express.js
It install well on windows and it gives you a good foundation to create a REST api.
http://expressjs.com/
You probably won't be using a view engine and just returning your payload using json or xml.
There is a nice article on using express for an api here:
http://pixelhandler.com/blog/2012/02/09/develop-a-restful-api-using-node-js-with-express-and-mongoose/

You don't need to use Mongoose or mongo as the data store, just pick whatever you choose, but the rest of the article will be helpful.

Comment: @theProgammer 
i need to send u my code i ve develop a service its working but i couldnt store in database Means i m not b able to insert the data into database if u can please help me out!!